# Jolt returns null after transforming but same works at http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

Tags: java, json, java-8, jolt

I am trying to transform the below JSON:

**From:**

```json
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": {
    "firstName": "shiva",
    "lastName": "kumar"
  },
  "dateOfBirth": "11/09/2012",
  "emailId": "mymail@gmail.com",
  "address": {
    "addressLine1": "blr",
    "addressLine2": "KA"
  },
  "salary": 12334
}
```

**to:**

```json
{
  "id": 123,
  "email": "mymail@gmail.com",
  "salary": 12334,
  "fullname": {
    "firstName": "shiva",
    "lastName": "kumar"
  },
  "fullAdress": "blr KA"
}
```

**Code:** The below code just return `null`.

```java
    private JSONObject tranformRequest(String json, String specFile){
    
            URI uri = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(specFile).toURI();
            String jsonSpec = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(uri)).stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonSpec);
            List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                list.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toMap());
            }
            Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(list);//  JsonUtils.classpathToList( "/path/to/chainr/spec.json" );
    
            Object output = chainr.transform( json );
    
            return (JSONObject) output;
        }

pom.xml

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolt-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

[[image: from jolt transformation tool online http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception][1]]

Comment: The latest version of jolt is `0.1.6`. please see the releases: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases

Comment: @MohammadReza I didn't get your point. is 0.1.7 in dev? I didn't see any errors about the version library version though. I mean the code compiles but fails while running the app

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bazaarvoice.jolt/jolt-core

Comment: I did not downvote your question. Your right. I saw `0.1.7` in the maven repository. I suggest trying version `0.1.1` too.

Comment: If jolt failed to convert your input JSON return `null`. So the problem may be from the jolt specification. I added an answer that might solve your problem. upvote +1

Comment: Same spec worked with online tool but fails with java code. Let me try with older version

Answer (score 0):

If jolt failed to convert your input JSON return `null`. So it can be for jolt specification.

Let's use the demo version of the site. Maybe the problem is solved.

Please update your package with version `0.1.1` like the [jolt-demo](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception) website, and use the below code.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "&",
      "name": "fullname",
      "emailId": "email",
      "salary": "salary",
      "address": {
        "*": "&1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join(' ',@0)"
    }
  }
]
```

If you have any problem please say in the comment.

Comment: Same spec worked with online tool but fails with java code. Let me try with older version